# overlay an image

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation, graphicmagick

I have two photos ( 1.jpg and 2.jpg) I want to make photo 2.jpg as a background and photo 1.jpg red colored overlay and I want the output to be like photo 3.jpg as follow ( I want to put photo number 1 on top of photo number 2 and make it transparent 50%):

**Photo 1.jpg ( overlay)**
[image]

**Photo 2.jpg ( background)**
[image]

**Photo 3.jpg ( final output)**
[image]

I tried the commands **convert and composite** ( part of ImageMagick but following multiple attempts I failed to figure out the correct flags that I should use)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will do the job:

```bash
composite -blend 30 1.jpg 2.jpg res.jpg
```

I used your pictures and here is the result:

[image: res.jpg]

If you want to make opacity of first image more or less, you shoud modify `-blend` param from 0 to 100 (with `-blend 0` your 1.jpg will be transparent, so result will be same as original 2.jpg. with `-blend 100` result will be same as 1.jpg. so with `-blend 50` you will get average opacity of both images)

```bash
composite -blend {{OPACITY_OF_1.JPG}}  1.jpg 2.jpg result.jpg
```

---

For GraphicsMagick users, this produces identical result:

```bash
gm composite -dissolve 30% 1.jpg 2.jpg res.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! You are awesome! Kindly is it possible to change the overlay color?

Comment: @goro, yes, you can do this. `convert 2.jpg 1.jpg -compose blend -define compose:args=30 -composite -set option:modulate:colorspace hsb -modulate 100,100,{{HUE_ROTATION_ANGLE}} result.jpg`.
"The hue argument causes a "rotation" of the colors within the image by the amount specified. For example, 50 results in a counter-clockwise rotation of 90, mapping red shades to purple, and so on..."


Learn more here: [imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#modulate](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#modulate)

Comment: I wanted to overlap two png images, `composite` without `-blend` option worked.

Comment: Wonder what the GraphicsMagick equivalent to this is? They seems to have removed the -blend option.

Comment: @DanJacobson [`-dissolve`](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-dissolve) seems to have the same effect in `gm`, I've updated the answer :)